# Diferencia entre render_template y redirect(url_for()) en Flask Python

Tags: python, flask, template, redirección

hace tiempo estoy desarrollando una app en Flask, y he trabajado tanto con `redirect(url_for())` como con `render_template`, y basicamente en obtenido (a mis ojos) el mismo resultado.
¿En que radica la diferencia y cuando debo usar una u otra funcion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues hay bastante diferencia. 
Con render_template ya has hecho toda la lógica y mandas a renderizar una plantilla entregando los datos necesarios ya establecidos y procesados.

Con redirect(url_for()) estás enviando el control a un método que debe procesar la lógica del mismo, preparar los datos y por último hacer el render_template

Sin render_template nunca verías una ruta, alguien tiene que renderizar la plantilla y básicamente es este método.

Answer (score 2):

No soy un especialista de Flask pero yo diría que **render_template** genera el contenido de la respuesta a partir de un template y **redirect**, traslada el testigo a otro url, quien será el encargado de entregar la respuesta.